# How do I get a shrink-to-fit navbar in html and css

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm using HTML and CSS and can't seem to figure out a way to get my nav bar to resize with my window. when I shrink the window I get this horrid stacking of icons from my navbar. is there any code there any codes that could help?
heres my code:

```
navbar{position: absolute;
    top: 145px;
    left: 20px;
    width: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #ff0000
}
navbar ul{
    font-size:42px;
}
navbar li{
    display: inline-block;
}
navbar a{
     border-right:2px solid #000000;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:0.9em;
    text-transform:uppercase
}
navbar li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #000001
    height: 50px;
    padding: 16px 12px;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
navbar li a:hover{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ff0000;
    transition: 1.0s ease;
}
navbar li.active a{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Show your code. Thats what we read here. 
Your description in text is cool but on same token you yourself 
admit that things are going wrong. 
Only source code will reveal the errors. 
If you could update your post with your source code it would be 
highly productive in someone finding the bug.also see [How To Ask Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I just posted the code

Comment: Is this solved? There are a few answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Code from resource but this is fine for you this is responsive `navbar` with **HTML** and **CSS**

This is Simple responsive **Navbar** with **HTML** and **CSS**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
}

.nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  position: relative;
}

.nav > .nav-header {
  display: inline;
}

.nav > .nav-header > .nav-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.nav > .nav-btn {
  display: none;
}

.nav > .nav-links {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.nav > .nav-links > a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 13px 10px 13px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #efefef;
}

.nav > .nav-links > a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.nav > #nav-check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .nav > .nav-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 13px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label:hover,.nav  #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-btn > label {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label > span {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #eee;
  }
  .nav > .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-links > a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav > #nav-check:not(:checked) ~ .nav-links {
    height: 0px;
  }
  .nav > #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-links {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
  <div class="nav-header">
    <div class="nav-title">
      Logo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-btn">
    <label for="nav-check">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="nav-links">
    <a href="//github.io/jo_geek" target="_blank">Github</a>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/4084003/" target="_blank">Stackoverflow</a>
    <a href="https://in.linkedin.com/in/jonesvinothjoseph" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a>
    <a href="https://codepen.io/jo_Geek/" target="_blank">Codepen</a>
    <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/user/jo_Geek/" target="_blank">JsFiddle</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And Second Option Use Bootstrap 4 for that you need to use some Bootstrap 4 **CDN** i.e **Content delivery network** use this CDN under `head` tag

**CDN**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is Simple Example Responsive Navbar with bootstrap 4

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="/examples/images/logo.svg" height="28" alt="CoolBrand">
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Profile</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Messages</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link disabled" tabindex="-1">Reports</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you are looking for [Link to W3 school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```